# R: install repr package

Tags: r, apache-zeppelin

I'm new to R, and I'm trying to use the following Apache Zeppelin with R interpreter installation: https://github.com/elbamos/Zeppelin-With-R/tree/rinterpreter-0.5.5

However, as the manuel says, one pre-requirement is the package "repr".
I tried to install it in the R console via

```
install.packages('repr')
```

but this wont work, I get the following error:

```
> install.packages('repr')
Installing package into â/usr/local/lib/R/site-libraryâ
(as âlibâ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package âreprâ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

The manual says following:

> For full R support and to view the demo notebook, you will also need the following R packages:
>
> knitr
>
> repr -- available with devtools::install_github("IRkernel/repr")
>
> ...

Can someone explain to me how to install the repr package? Thank you!

Comment: like suggested in your website, have you tried to install it with devtools::install_github("IRkernel/repr")?

Comment: The warning message is quite clear: For your version, the `repr` package is not available on CRAN (yet).

Comment: Try using different CRAN. May be a htttp CRAN instead of https

Answer (score 3):

Run this in R:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("IRkernel/repr")
```